# Changing the position of scaling

Tags: positioning, graphs, axis

when i run this code, I get a 10^4 on the bottom right, which seem strictly false. I would like to get rid of this one. And on the top left I have the scaling for the y-axis. I would either like it to be on the left of the axis or get rid of it and write ylabel = {$E[\pi_R]$ in $10^9$},

```
 \documentclass[letter,11pt,twoside]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.5}
\definecolor{dark-gray}{gray}{0.2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  labelnode/.style={font=\footnotesize, above},
  labelline/.style={stealth-stealth,shorten >=0.1pt, shorten <=0.5pt}
]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $c_{S_2}$,
    ylabel = {$E[\pi_R]$},
    width=14cm,
    height=8cm,
    xmin=9900, xmax=10100, ymin=6.7*10^9, ymax=8.4*10^9,
xtick={9900,9950,10000,10050,10100},
xticklabels={9900,9950,10000,10050,10100},
]
\addplot [
    domain=9900 : 10000,
    samples=100,
    style=dashed,
    color=dark-gray   ] {24500000000/3 - 5/4 * x* (40000 + 3 * x)} ; %notcare1 check

\coordinate (l) at (rel axis cs:0,1);

\legend{$E[\dot{\pi}_R]$,$E[\tilde{\pi}_R]$}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add `scaled ticks=false`.

```
\documentclass[letter,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.5}
\definecolor{dark-gray}{gray}{0.2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  labelnode/.style={font=\footnotesize, above},
  labelline/.style={stealth-stealth,shorten >=0.1pt, shorten <=0.5pt}
]
\begin{axis}[scaled ticks=false,
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $c_{S_2}$,
    ylabel = {$E[\pi_R]$},
    width=14cm,
    height=8cm,
    xmin=9900, xmax=10100, ymin=6.7*10^9, ymax=8.4*10^9,
xtick={9900,9950,10000,10050,10100},
xticklabels={9900,9950,10000,10050,10100},
]
\addplot [
    domain=9900:10000,
    samples=100,
    style=dashed,
    color=dark-gray   ] {24500000000/3 - 5/4 * x* (40000 + 3 * x)} ; %notcare1 check

\coordinate (l) at (rel axis cs:0,1);

\legend{$E[\dot{\pi}_R]$,$E[\tilde{\pi}_R]$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]